# Google App Engine with Spring Cloud GCP: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, spring-data-jpa

I am attempting to deploy a (non-packaged) Spring Boot web app to Google App Engine using the default starters. I keep the same error: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url'

I am attempting to follow the instruction in this resource: https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/spring-cloud-gcp

## What I tried

### pom.xml

You can see that I as attempting to use Flyway to initialize the database, but decided to skip it for now during troubleshooting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>nathanlively</groupId>
    <artifactId>subaligner-css</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>subaligner</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <!-- Maven plugins -->
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.12.1</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>v19.8.1</frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion>9.5.1</frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>4.1.4</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency><!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- gcloud stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.svg</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>subaligner-382913</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-frontend-tooling</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion}</nodeVersion>
                                <npmVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion}</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-npm-install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-npm-build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-npm-build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build-prod</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

### bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.project-id=subaligner-382913
```

### application.properties

Here you can see that I attempted to set the active profile in the app.yaml file, but that didn't seem to work.

```
spring.profiles.active=deploy  # This is set in app.yaml.

# ===============================
# = JPA / Hibernate
# ===============================
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=21MB

# ===============================
# = API
# ===============================
soundVelocityUrl=https://nathanlively.pythonanywhere.com/speedOfSound/?

# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf Config
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order=0
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages

# ===============================
# = MVC Config
# ===============================
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

# ===============================
# = Redis Config
# ===============================
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=60000
spring.cache.redis.cache-null-values=true
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
```

### application-deploy.properties

Here I attempted to use the database user I created. I'm not sure if that's actually part of the problem, so I commented it out to force it to just use the root user.

```
# ===============================
# = Deployed Database Config
# ===============================
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=subaligner-382913:us-central1:subaligner-java
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=subaligner_java
#spring.datasource.username=${sm://DB_USER/latest}
#spring.datasource.password=${sm://DB_PASSWORD/latest}
#spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# ===============================
# = Flyway Database Config
# ===============================
#spring.flyway.enabled=true
#spring.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://${spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name}:3306/${spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name}
#spring.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql:///subaligner_java?cloudSqlInstance=subaligner-java&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=${sm://DB_USERFLYWAY/latest}&password=${sm://DB_PASSWORDFLY/latest}
#spring.flyway.user=${sm://DB_USERFLYWAY/latest}
#spring.flyway.password=${sm://DB_PASSWORDFLY/latest}
```

### app.yaml

I have this in the root, but app engine seems to be ignoring it.

```
# app.yaml
runtime: java17
instance_class: B1  # Upgrade this later to F1 and automatic scaling

env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "deploy"
```

## What actually resulted

```
2023-04-12 02:52:00 default[1]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503
2023-04-12 02:52:03 default[1]  02:52:03.941 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
2023-04-12 02:52:04 default[1]  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A database name must be provided.   at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:294)     at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.sql.DefaultCloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider.<init>(DefaultCloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider.java:37)    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.sql.CloudSqlEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(CloudSqlEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:55)      at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)     at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)   at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)     at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)   at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:354)    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)      at nathanlively.subalignercss.SubalignerApplication.main(SubalignerApplication.java:13)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

Comment: I think you need to fill in the `spring.datasource` properties in your `application-deploy.properties` file. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ for an example of how that's done.

Comment: Thanks @ZackMacomber , according to the example [here](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/databases/cloud-sql#configuration) 

> # Cloud SQL starter automatically configures the JDBC URL

Comment: Ok, it took me a day to realize that the way I was attempting to create an in-line comment in the application.properties file was stopping application-deploy.properties from ever running. Now I'm getting a different error related to the DB login credentials, but I'm going to leave the question the way it is in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am still not able to successfully deploy to app engine, as far as I can tell this particular problem has been solved and I'm on to a new one.

Here were some of the mistakes:

1. I guess you can't use in-line comment in the application.properties file, so application-deploy.properties was never actually being used. I blame Intellij for not helping me with that one. ;)
2. Even after reading the documentation very carefully, I was still under the impression that loading the spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql dependency also loaded mysql and secrets and everything I needed. Turns out it's the other way around. spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql includes the gcp-starter, so you only need the mysql one.
3. I had instance-connection-name set to the instance name instead of the full instance-connection-name.

Now I'm having a JPA error, but I'll post that in a new question.

On a person level, I'm kind of disappointed that I couldn't get anyone from Google to jump in here to help. According to their own documentation, this is where you should ask for help.

Comment: This is not an answer. Either update your question or delete it and ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks John. This is the best I could come up with. Much appreciation if would take the time to submit another answer.